# Most user friendly way to present exclusive archetypes with nested configuration options

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, radio-buttons

I'm currently implementing a UI for a configuration application. The typical user would be an employee changing the configuration parameters of some client software (like theme, available features to the actual user of the client software, ...).

At some points, the user has to choose one of multiple archetypes (with one being preselected) and can then configure additional settings specific to that archetype.

In other words, the logical layout looks e.g. like this:

```
General Configuration Page
  │
  │
  └ Archetype Selection
      │
      ├ Archetype A
      │   │
      │   ├ "A" specific setting
      │   │
      │   └ "A" specific setting
      │
      │
      └ Archetype B
          │
          ├ "B" specific setting
          │
          └ "B" specific setting
```

We currently have this logical layout mapped to the following UI (mockup):
[image: Current UI mockup]

We have a radio button for each archetype and the sub-settings in an additional panel below the corresponding option.

Obviously, the exact parameters of the logical side can change, e.g. more archetypes, or more sub-settings, or some archetypes without sub-settings.

Is this UI layout working out in terms of UX?

What could we improve?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in what Consistency and standards heuristics says:

**Consistency and standards**
Users should not have to wonder whether different words, situations, or actions mean the same thing.

- success rate of 80% when people used the navigation scheme structured according to most users' mental model
- success rate of 9% when people used the navigation scheme structured according to the company's internal thinking

Conclusion: the second navigation scheme was dropped from the design, even though this pained some of the project members. The second scheme had its advantages for those people who used it correctly, but it led most users into trouble, so it did more harm than good.

[4th Heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/do-interface-standards-stifle-design-creativity/)

You can Try an Steps-Selection instead of a tree, like e-commerse pages when you are closing your purchase:

1st, Confirm products

2nd, confirm Account

3rd, Payment

4th, Shippment options

5th, Finish

In your case can be:

1st, Select Theme

2nd, Select Features

3rd, Select Roles

4th, Finish

Or something like that, with yuor Sub-Archetypes